# How to display filtered data (when the user types something in input field) only if a Search btn is clicked

Tags: reactjs, button, search, input, field

I am working on a React project. I am trying to implement search functionality.
So far, everything is working as I expect, but what I am looking for exactly is to display the filtered data only if the user clicks on a "Search" btn next to the input field, and not to display the data once the user begins to type something on the input.
Here is the code of 2 relevant components , UsersHeader being the child of Users:

```
function Users() {
  const [filteredResults, setFilteredResults] = React.useState([]);
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = React.useState("");
  const searchItems = (searchValue) => {
    setSearchInput(searchValue);
    if (searchInput !== "") {
      const filteredData = UsersCollection.filter((user) => {
        return (
          Object.values(user.userName)
            .join("")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchInput.toString().toLowerCase()) ||
          Object.values(user.email)
            .join("")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchInput.toString().toLowerCase()) ||
          Object.values(user.country)
            .join("")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchInput.toString().toLowerCase()) ||
          Object.values(user.company)
            .join("")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchInput.toString().toLowerCase()) ||
          Object.values(user.registrationDate)
            .join("")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchInput.toString().toLowerCase())
        );
      });
      setFilteredResults(filteredData);
    } else {
      setFilteredResults(UsersCollection);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "100px 100px 100px 300px" }}>
      <div>
        <UsersHeader {...{ searchItems, searchInput }}></UsersHeader>
      </div>

      <div>
        {searchInput?.length >= 1 ? ( //if something is being typed in the search input field
          <UserList filteredResults={filteredResults} />
        ) : (
          <UserList
            searchInput={searchInput}
            UsersCollection={UsersCollection}
          ></UserList>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Users;
```

```
export function UsersHeader({ searchItems }) {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState();
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    // setSearchValue(e.target.value);
    searchItems(e.target.value);
  };
  const handlePressEnter = () => {
    handleClick();
  };
  const handleClick = () => {};

  return (
    <div className="user-header">
      <div>
        <Button
          className="user-header-filter-btn"
          style={{ width: "fit-content", height: "fit-content" }}
        >
          <img src={filterIcon} alt="" />
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Input
          value={searchValue}
          onChange={(e) => {
            searchItems(e.target.value);
          }}
          className="user-header-input"
          style={{ width: "800px" }}
          placeholder=" &nbsp;Search by keyword"
          allowClear
          onPressEnter={(e) => {
            handlePressEnter(e);
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={handleClick} className="user-header-search-btn">
          <Search />
          <span>Search</span>
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is that you're returning the filter on typing.
what you should do is remove the code that is responsible for returning filtered messages into a separate function that is triggered at the click of the search button.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearchInput(e.target.value);
//searchItems(e.target.value);
};

const searchItems = () => {
//setSearchInput(searchValue);
if (searchInput !== "") {
  const filteredData = UsersCollection.filter((user) => {
    return (
      Object.values(user.userName)
        .join("")
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchInput.toString().toLowerCase()) ||
      Object.values(user.email)
        .join("")
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchInput.toString().toLowerCase()) ||
      Object.values(user.country)
        .join("")
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchInput.toString().toLowerCase()) ||
      Object.values(user.company)
        .join("")
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchInput.toString().toLowerCase()) ||
      Object.values(user.registrationDate)
        .join("")
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchInput.toString().toLowerCase())
    );
  });
  setFilteredResults(filteredData);
} else {
  setFilteredResults(UsersCollection);
}}

const handleClick = () => {searchItems()};
```

Comment: Ok , thanks ,will try this now ! and I will get back to you !

Comment: please, can you help solve another problem , related to the same component ?

Comment: post it and tag me

Comment: Ok,  I will , tomorow

Comment: Hey @Zein , so the problem I encounter now is : when I search for a specific user for example  by its username from the list of users, the results that are shown right away (without clicking the Search button) are results of the previous search. It is only when I click on 'Enter key' or on the btn, that the new results are shown in the UI. so , how can I fix this issue please ? here is a demo of the problem in this video : https://streamable.com/di73pr

Comment: @AbdelmounimSIFELHAK please post it as a new issue and add all of the responsible code for this table

Comment: ok I will , in this same post ?

Comment: @AbdelmounimSIFELHAK different please

Comment: ok  I will ,can you try to help me with this problem also ?      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74181313/how-to-display-an-image-in-a-child-component-based-on-a-prop-function-that-retur                                
                  it seems that I am complicating things...

Comment: can you help with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74206315/in-react-how-to-be-redirected-to-a-new-page-but-still-keep-a-drawer-component-o ??