# how to display an image in a child component based on a prop function that returns the src of the img in React

Tags: reactjs, image, src, prop

I am trying to render an img on the UI which source is controlled by a function that a child component receives, this function is declared in a 5-level parent component and is being passed down to all children, until it reaches the child component which will render it.
The problem that I am facing is that the img tag is empty, it is as if the src attribute has not been determined, so no image appears.
The function returns the URL of the img based on the name of a workout.
Here is the code for the parent component :

```
const Chest = ({}) => {
  const { workouts, dispatch } = useWorkoutsContext();
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWorkouts = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("/api/workouts");
      const json = await response.json();
      if (response.ok) {
        dispatch({ type: "SET_WORKOUTS", payload: json });
      }
    };
    fetchWorkouts();
  }, [dispatch]);

  const setSocialExoImage = (imagePath) => {
    for (var workout of workouts) {
      let title = workout.title;
        switch (title) {
        case "Chest Flye":
          imagePath =
            "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/YWaPGifbdz6dgiUSCmHp2E.jpg";
          break;
        case "Pause Push-Up":
          imagePath = "      "https://gethealthyu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Chest-Flies_Exercise.jpg";
          break;
        case "Barbell Flat Bench Press":
          imagePath = "https://media.self.com/photos/57d889aef71ce8751f6b48f8/4:3/w_2560%2Cc_limit/push-uptips_Feat.jpg";
          break;
        case "Barbell Test":
          imagePath = "";
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
    return imagePath;
  };
 return (
      <>
        <div className="chest-page-container">
          <div className="chest-workouts">
            <WorkoutsSection
              {...{ setSocialExoImage, workouts, currentPage }}
            ></WorkoutsSection>
          </div>
          <div className="chest-form">
            <WorkoutForm />
          </div>
          <BackTop />
        </div>
        <Pagination
          style={{
            border: `1px solid lightgray`,
            padding: `50px 0`,
          }}
          className="pagination-content-loaded"
          total={
            workouts.length > 0 && workouts.length <= 10
              ? 30 //3 pages
              : workouts.length >= 10 && workouts.length <= 20
              ? 60 //6 pages
              : workouts.length >= 20 && workouts.length <= 30
              ? 90
              : workouts.length >= 30 && workouts.length <= 40
              ? 120
              : workouts.length >= 40 && workouts.length <= 50
              ? 150
              : workouts.length >= 50 && workouts.length <= 60
              ? 180
              : 250
          }
          // total={200} //200 means 20 page
          current={currentPage}
          onChange={(page, e) => {
            setCurrentPage(page);
          }}
          showSizeChanger={false}
          showQuickJumper
        />
      </>
    );
  }
```

and the code of the child component :

```
export function SocialModalContent({ workoutTitle, setSocialExoImage }) {
  console.log(setSocialExoImage);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>
          {`Hey ! I want you to come take a look at this chest workout ! Thanks !`}
        </p>
        <span>It's called : </span> <span>{workoutTitle}</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src={setSocialExoImage()} alt="" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <Button>
          <img src="" alt="" />
          <span>Share</span>
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

consoling out 'setSocialExoImage' in the child component  gives :

```
 imagePath => {
    for (var workout of workouts) {
      let title = workout.title;

      switch (title) {
        case "Chest Flye":
          imagePath = "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/YWaPGif…
```

Comment: please post your code on sandbox and send a link I can't determine the problem from this code

Comment: do I need to post just these 2 components or the child components in between ?

Comment: @Zein , here is a sandbox :  https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-kilby-chkmug?file=/package.json:825-831

Comment: never mind , I just solved the prb , it was due to a space that was preceding the 1st letter of the title of the workout, that made this statement :  ```  
 for (let i = 0; i < workouts?.length; i++) {
      let title = workouts[i].title;
      switch (title) {
        case ` Chest Flye`:
          imagePath = `https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/YWaPGifbdz6dgiUSCmHp2E.jpg`;
          break; ``` returns false