# in react, How to be redirected to a new page but still keep a drawer component opened

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am working on a React project.
I am facing this issue: I want the user to watch a video corresponding to a chest workout if he clicks on a video icon that is nested in a drawer of antd library component (this component also contains other information like the workout title...)
I want the user to be redirected to this page without the drawer being closed, (the drawer occupies 50% of the page's width, and the rest of the page is covered with a greyish bg color, but still visible),  and then he can navigate again to the previous info if he clicks on a "back" btn.
The code of app.js

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
// pages & components
import { ListOfExercises } from "./components/lists/ListOfExercises";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import ChestWorkouts from "./pages/Chest";
import ChestVideoWorkouts from "./pages/ChestVideoWorkouts";
import Home from "./pages/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <ListOfExercises></ListOfExercises>

      <div className="pages">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/chest" element={<ChestWorkouts />} />
          <Route path="/video-workout" element={<ChestVideoWorkouts />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

WorkoutInfosDrawer is a child of WorkoutDetails which is a child of WorkoutsSection which is a child of the ChestWorkouts page
and of  WorkoutInfosDrawer.js:

```
import "./drawer_content_styles.scss";
import { WorkoutInfos } from "./WorkoutInfos";

export function WorkoutInfosDrawer({ workoutTitle, setsize }) {
  function infos() {
    let infos =
      workoutTitle === "Barbell Flat Bench Press"
        ? {
            description:
              "The bench press is a classic exercise. Powerlifters do it to see who has the most pressing strength, gym rats use it to build up their pecs, and athletes utilize the bench for explosive pushing power.            ",
            benefits: {
              b1: "This lift is a necessiry for powerlifters, since it’s one of the three lifts judged in a powerlifting meet.",
              b2: "The bench press recruits muscles in the chest, triceps, and shoulders — so you’ll build a muscular torso",
              b3: "Compared to other chest exercises, you can load the bench press up with a relatively heavy amount of weight.",
            },
            howToDo:
              "Lay back down on a bench, arch your lower back slightly, and plant your feet on the floor. Pull your shoulder blades together to enhance stability and upper back strength. Grab the bar (varying grips) and squeeze the hand hard to flex the arm and grip muscles maximally. With the load unracked, think about pulling the barbell to the body to touch the sternum/base of the chest. Press the weight upwards, making sure to keep your back tight, and shoulder blades pulled together.",
          }
        : "";
    return infos;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <WorkoutInfos
        {...{
          setsize,
          workoutTitle,
        }}
        infos={infos()}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

and of WorkoutInfos.js: , the Link tag is being used here :

```
import { Button } from "antd";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import minus from "../../assets/img/minus.png";
import plus from "../../assets/img/plus-sign.svg";
import videoPlayer from "../../assets/img/video.svg";
import "./drawer_content_styles.scss";

export const WorkoutInfos = ({ workoutTitle, infos, setsize }) => {

  return (
    <div className="workout-infos" style={{ paddingBottom: paddingBottom }}>
      <div className="workout-infos-left">
        <div className="workout-infos-title">
          <span>{workoutTitle}</span>
        </div>

        <div className="workout-infos-other-infos">
          <div className="workout-infos-span1-wrapper">
            <span>{infos?.description}</span>
          </div>

          <div className="workout-infos-span2-wrapper">
            <span className="workout-infos-span1">
              The workout's benefits :
            </span>
            <div className="workout-infos-span2-wrapper-div">
              <span className="workout-infos-span2">{infos?.benefits?.b1}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="workout-infos-span2-wrapper-div">
              <span className="workout-infos-span3">{infos?.benefits?.b2}</span>
            </div>
            {infos?.benefits?.b3 && (
              <div className="workout-infos-span2-wrapper-div">
                <span className="workout-infos-span4">
                  {infos?.benefits?.b3}
                </span>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>

          <div className="workout-infos-howto-do">
            <span className="workout-infos-howto-do-span1">How to do it :</span>
          </div>

          <div className="workout-infos-sign">
            <div style={{ overflow: overflow, height: height }}>
              <span className="workout-infos-sign-span">{infos?.howToDo}</span>
            </div>
            <Button className="workout-infos-sign-btn" onClick={handleBtnClick}>
              {overflow === "hidden" ? (
                <img src={plus} alt="" />
              ) : (
                <img src={minus} alt="" />
              )}
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="workout-infos-right">
        <Link to="/video-workout">
          <Button className="workout-infos-sign-btn">
            <img src={videoPlayer} alt="" />
          </Button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: can you post the code on sandbox and send a link please

Comment: never mind , I have solved the prblm by using antd Steps components , but I am facing another prblm now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74211176/react-app-issue-cross-origin-read-blocking-corb-blocked-cross-origin-respons

Comment: @Zein , hey man , please can you help me with this issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74273150/how-to-update-a-workout-in-a-crud-mern-react-application

Answer (score 0):

Since the drawer component is nested deep inside `<ChestWorkouts />`, it's not going to render when you aren't rendering `<ChestWorkouts />` anymore.

The key here is to structure your components such that the drawer component is not nested within any of the routes, so it doesn't disappear when its parent component does. Perhaps you could place the drawer component outside `<Routes />` like you've done with `<Navbar />` (which is the reason why Navbar doesn't disappear on route changes).

You can place the drawer at the root of your component tree and manage its state by passing it down other routed components or perhaps through redux.

Comment: thanks sir I will try this now, but React router nested routes won't solve the problem ?? I was reading this article to try implement this: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-nested-routes/#:~:text=Nested%20Routes%20are%20a%20powerful,based%20on%20the%20current%20route.

Comment: I will use Steps ant component instead ; it will solve the problem : https://ant.design/components/steps/#components-steps-demo-nav

Comment: hey man , please can you help me with this issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74273150/how-to-update-a-workout-in-a-crud-mern-react-application